# Updating python dictionary elements gives a [ ]

Tags: python, mongodb, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have my code here like this, i want to update some items inside a list:

```
coordinates = mongo_query.get_items({})
for json in coordinates:
     json["person"] = "test"
     json["location"] = "test"
     for j in range(0, len(json["types"])):
         json["types"][j] =  "test"
new_coordinates = coordinates
```

here when i debug the variable  new_coordinates is empty like this: `'[]'`

The results of coordinates if I do `json_util.dumps(coordinates)` it gives this:

```
   coordinates= [{"name": "my name", "timestamp": {"$date": 1459002562091}, "longitude": 20.169550966746304, "location": "Work", "victim": {"language": "English", "locality": "Bern", "gender": "Other", "region": "Gabon", "birthday": {"$date": 506736000000}, "nationality": "United States", "ethnicity": "Bosnian"}, "person": "Stranger", "latitude": 43.05529651674635, "personGender": "Male", "types": ["Shouting"]}, {"name": "my name", "timestamp": {"$date": 1455632962091}, "longitude": 21.292620354706038, "location": "Public Space", "victim": {"language": "English", "locality": "Ferizaj", "gender": "Other", "region": "Kosovo", "birthday": {"$date": 601516800000}, "nationality": "Canada", "ethnicity": "Turkish"}, "person": "Waiter", "latitude": 42.81558228232729, "personGender": "Male", "types": ["Comments", "Whistling"]}]
```

why is this happening I don't get why I can't update elements on the coordinates list, and why it gives an empty list? Can somebody help me?

Edit :

So see the coordinates better here: [Jsonblob link](http://jsonblob.com/56e01ee8e4b01190df53a785)

Comment: Would you mind pretty-printing `coordinates`? It's a little weird to read currently.

Comment: @erip please check the edit that i made, I added a jsonblob link so u can see it better?

Comment: @erip any idea how is that happening?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the Python MongoDB API. `new_coordinates` is still an empty list after the assignment? I'd try `new_coordinates = [json for json in coordinates]` to make a deep copy anyway.

Comment: post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I tried like that or to append json item in another list but then when I get those coordinates inside script on the map var coordinates = {{coordinates|safe}}; it treats them as a string and this is a much bigger problem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath all the code that i posted is real except the test string variables..

Comment: @EgzEst: the code you've posted has no problems. looks like you've only posted a snippet assuming the problem is there, but it's not.

Comment: You're wasting our time.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I found doing that id after updating the list, it is updated as a py mongo instance but after that I do json_util.dumps(coordinates) gives me a blank list?

Answer (score 1):

I've repeated your code, importing the `coordinates = <your .json file>` and I was able to modify the coordinates - note only that you miss-spelled "person" as "peron".

I would investigate:

- Are you sure you don't do nothing with coordinates after all?
  Note that `something = other_something` is not the same as saying that `something = copy(other_something)`.
- Is the coordinates variable that you printed out inside a list [coordinates].
- I would recommend you to repeat my procedure on a python shell:`coordinates = <copy the content that you've output through that link>` and give it a try in one of the elements. This works for me:

  ```
  coordinates = # copy the stuff here [ {} ]
  for json in coordinates:
      json['person'] = 'bla'
  new_coordinates = coordinates
  new_coordinates
  ```

  which outputs: `[{'person': 'bla',...`